# EGit and multiple "users" on same machine

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, multi-user

I'd like to work with multiple git-based open source projects from the same machine. For each project, I'd like to associate a differnet `user.name` and `user.email` as appropriate. For instance, I might want to work on some project called `fizz` that is hosted on GitHub, and also work on another project called `buzz` that has its own privately-hosted, centralized git server/repo.

For the `fizz` project, I'd like to use `myname@example.com` as my email, so that when I push changes to the master branch, other collaborators see that as my username/email.

But for the `buzz` project, I'd like to user `myname@someotherdomain.example.com`, so that when I push changes to its master, collaborators on the `buzz` project so that as my email.

Unless I'm mistaken, EGit seems to only allow me to configure 1 `user.name` and `user.email`. How can I get around this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git configuration is stored in the following files, and when looking up configuration, it is tried in the following order (see [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)):

1. Local: `.git/config` in the current repository
2. Global: `.gitconfig` in the user's home directory
3. System: `gitconfig` in the system configuration directory (e.g. `/etc` on Linux)

So to configure `user.email` differently for a specific repository, do the following:

1. Open the properties of a repository from the *Git Repositories* view
2. In the *Configuration* tab, click on *Add Entry...*
3. Enter `user.email` as the key and the desired value
4. Click OK

The repository configuration can also be changed from the preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > Repository Settings.

Note that in Git, `user.name` should be a real full name such as `Jane Doe`.