# Using multiple Git accounts

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Is it possible to have multiple git accounts in `Eclipse(egit)` and choose which one to use each time?

*Example:*
I currently have a git account, with *username: workuser* and *email: workuser@company.com* and this account is used for the company's repositories.

I want to use another account which will be used for my github repositories and will not have any relation to the first account (*workuser*), e.g. *username:githubuser* and *email: anothermail@something.com*

Is it possible to have both accounts and choose each time which account will be used in order to work on the related repositories(different for work and github) ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19032708/305973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about egit, but by default, `git config` (without `--global`) stores values in repository-specific file, so the only thing you need to do is:

```
$ cd project-repo
$ git config user.name "<name>"
$ git config user.email "<mail>"
```